# Sorting vertices in graph adjacency list in clockwise order

Tags: c++, sorting, graph, adjacency-list

I have a planar graph represented as array of circular linked lists.
Each list represents a vertex with its adjacent vertices.

I need to sort vertices in each adjacency list in clockwise planar order.

I don't have any ideas how to do that. Are there any algorithms?

Comment: Do you have planar coordinates with each vertex? If so, you can sort adjacent vertices based on the direction vector to the 'central' vertex using `atan2(dir.y, dir.x)`.

Comment: Yes, I can find them if required. I will do so, if won't find any better solution. It requires in worst case O(V^2*log(V)) time. Not really acceptable complexity.

Comment: How did you derive that big-Oh? IIRC, the number of edges in a planar graph is O(V), so this solution would run in O(V*log(V)) time.

Comment: I need to sort adjacent vertices for each vertex - so overall complexity is V*O(V*log(V)) = O(V^2*log(V))

Comment: It should be possible to do the task without coordinates. Using coordinates may not give correct answer, in my graph a lot of vertices have same X or Y coordinate so have same angle with central vertex.

Comment: Seems like you misunderstood. I've elaborated in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since you indicated in the comments that you have planar coordinates, here is a solution that uses them (in pseudo-code). Basically, you sort the adjacent vertices `a` of each vertex `v` in ascending order of the `atan2` of the vector from the vertex to the adjacent vertex `(a - v)`.

```
struct Point
{
    x, y;
};
// assume Point has overloaded arithmetic operators

void sortAdjacentVertices(Point v, list<Point> adjacentVertices)
{
    map<double, Point> sorted;
    for each (a in adjacentVertices)
    {
        Point dir = a - v;
        sorted[atan2(dir.y, dir.x)] = a;
    }
    adjacentVertices.clear();
    for each (a in sorted)
    {
        adjacentVertices.push(a.value);
    }
}
```

Calling this function for each vertex of the graph will run in O(V * log(V)), where V is the number of vertices, assuming the adjacency lists can be obtained in O(1). This is because each edge is examined exactly once (for directed graph) or twice (for undirected graph) and the [number of edges in a planar graph is O(V)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph#Other_planarity_criteria).

Comment: I don't understand how this can be O(V * log(V)). Each for loop is O(n) and number of function calls is number of vertices - therefore overall complexity is O(n^2) assuming insertion and search in map are O(1). However they are O(log(n)) so overall complexity is the same as I calculated in main post comment. Maybe you have misunderstood me? I'm calculating overall complexity - for sorting all adjacency list, not only one.

Comment: The number of adjacent vertices for any vertex is O(V), but the average number of adjacent vertices for all vertices in a planar graph is O(1). A single vertex can be connected to all others, but they can't all be. At least not for a planar graph of size V>3.

Comment: I got it, thanks. So asymptotically this solution is ok, however it requires coordinates, what as I described above is not good.